# Pandas merge dataframes with different datato achieve specific output

Tags: python, pandas

I'm experimenting with pandas, and facing with merge problem, f.e

print df

```
                                    0                         1         2
0                          plot_title                    title1    title2
1                             x_title                         x         x
2                             y_title                     Speed         y
3                              x_val0                       xv0       NaN
4                              x_val1                       xv1        v1
5                                exp1                    3159.6      3200
6                                exp2                    2441.2       NaN
```

print df_to merge

```
            0      1
0  plot_title  title
1     x_title      x
2     y_title     ro
3       x_val    Nan
4        exp1     19
5        exp7    127
```

and I want to achieve

```
                                    0      1          2      3
0                          plot_title  title1    title2  title
1                             x_title       x         x      x
2                             y_title   Speed         y     ro
3                              x_val0     xv0       NaN    NaN
4                              x_val1     xv1        v1    NaN
5                                exp1  3159.6      3200     19
6                                exp2  2441.2       NaN    Nan
7                                exp7     NaN       NaN    127
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

**UPDATE**:
After jeanrjc answer i get an key error

```
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3812)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3749)
KeyError: '0',
```

but if I run it with

df2 = df.merge(df_to merge, how='outer', left_on="0", right_on=0). I get

such df2 on output:

```
            0       1           0      1
0  plot_title  title1  plot_title  title
1     x_title       x     x_title      x
2     y_title   Speed     y_title     ro
3      x_val0     xv0      x_val0    NaN
4      x_val1     xv1      x_val1    NaN
5        exp1  3159.6        exp1     19
6        exp2  2441.2        exp2    NaN
7       x_val     NaN       x_val    Nan
8        exp7     NaN        exp7    127
```

Comment: merge() will do it.  Might need to rename 2 of your columns post merge

Comment: can you expand your answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a merge with "outer" mode:

```
df2 = df.merge(df_to merge, how='outer', left_on="0", right_on="0")
```

and rename your columns :

```
df2.columns = range(4)
```

which gives:

```
            0       1       2      3
0  plot_title  title1  title2  title
1     x_title       x       x      x
2     y_title   Speed       y     ro
3      x_val0     xv0     NaN    NaN
4      x_val1     xv1      v1    NaN
5        exp1  3159.6    3200     19
6        exp2  2441.2     NaN    NaN
7       x_val     NaN     NaN    Nan
8        exp7     NaN     NaN    127
```

Note that `x_val` from df_to_merge isn't in your expected output, I guess it's a mistake, isn't it ?

edit:

To reorder the rows:

```
df2 = df2.reindex(index=[1,2,3,4,7,5,6,8])
df2.index = range(1,9)
```

which gives:

```
         0       1     2    3
1  x_title       x     x    x
2  y_title   Speed     y   ro
3   x_val0     xv0   NaN  NaN
4   x_val1     xv1    v1  NaN
5    x_val     NaN   NaN  Nan
6     exp1  3159.6  3200   19
7     exp2  2441.2   NaN  NaN
8     exp7     NaN   NaN  127
```

HTH

Comment: Unfortunately:                                                                                       File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3812)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3749)
KeyError: '0'

Comment: Did you put quotes around the `0` ?

Comment: @DmitryMarkovnikov, What version of Pandas do you have ?

Comment: @DmitryMarkovnikov: Based on your update, it looks like `df` has string column names, and `df_to_merge` has integer column names. Thus, you were force to use `left_on='0'`, `right_on=0`. If you make both dataframes have string column names, e.g. `df_to_merge.columns = map(str, df_to_merge.columns)`, then I think `jeanrjc`'s solution will work.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu, you was right, this error apeeared because of different column names type. It worked.

Comment: dear @jeanrjc how can I merge this two dataframes and achieve x_val to be in x_val's group? and not to be in exp's group ( I describe it on your answer)